# Methods to send data to internet?

Tags: python, http

I'm an electronics guy, I've previously sent data from a hardware device running python under Linux(raspberry pi) to my shared hosting server using the 'get' method which wrote the data on a csv file on the server. This was the first method I found and it worked and the data traffic was also very low(server got the get/post request roughly every 2-3 minutes).

 
Two php files were on the server, one was appending the data to the csv file and other was displaying the data of csv file.
What are other methods to store/push the data like sensor values on to a database with timestamps, I've heard about socket programming but never used it. For this new application 2-3 data string will be generated every second for about one hour then there will be no requests for 4-5 hours. I just have to push the data to server and the website devs can take care of displaying and processing.

I'm good at python programming.

What are other methods to send data to internet using python?

If you want more information please let me know in the comments

Comment: Don't be afraid to stick with GET and POST. A great many very large apps use nothing more than those.

Comment: HTTP uses sockets underneath, it's just a lower-level interface.  You would need a server which understands your new protocol, too, if you move away from HTTP.  I'd concur, stick with HTTP unless it's obvious that it cannot scale (and maybe even then scale up the server side rather than create a different kind of complexity).

Comment: If the server-side database has a network interface of its own, maybe writing straight to the database would be quicker.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee I now understand the what sockets are.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP at the moment is a protocol widely used to send data over the internet cause usually firewall allow incoming & outgoing traffic on port 80 (http) and 443 (https). This means that you will have no problems sending data over the net on these ports.

In your case the amount of data send over the wire is not huge so you could just serialize data using JSON, XML or Protobuf and send them using HTTP/HTTPS. On the other side the php application would handle authentication, authorisation and data persistence on the disk (file, database, queue, etc)

If you're interested to go further with telemetry you could take a look at [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/).

> MQTT is a machine-to-machine (M2M)/"Internet of Things" connectivity protocol. It was designed as an extremely lightweight publish/subscribe messaging transport. It is useful for connections with remote locations where a small code footprint is required and/or network bandwidth is at a premium.

MQTT could be a better solution than data over HTTP. Please read [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/sowhatfordevs/entry/using_mqtt_protocol_advantages_over_http_in_mobile_application_development5?lang=en) to see the difference between the 2 approaches

Comment: Thanks @scott4dev my research on MQTT led me to node red, which pretty awesome and easy to use